# CSS :last-of-type pseudo-class right after :not

Tags: css

I just realized I don't understand how `:last-of-type` pseudo-class works. A simple example: I have a table with last sticky column, I want to select all cells (`td`s) placed right before the last sticky cell (with a class `ds-dt-sticky-cell`).

```
table tr td:not(.ds-dt-sticky-cell):last-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

As expected, if I remove `:last-of-type` part, it selects all cells but sticky ones. In a DOM-tree everything looks good:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Is it code/data/error? It's a partial snapshot of the DOM tree I mentioned here.

Comment: Is the DOM *not* code?!? How else are answerers going to reproduce the issue but with HTML to run the CSS against? If you want to make your question harder to answer, by all means, keep the necessary code hidden away in an image.

Comment: @Evgeny i just changed my answer substantially based on some research. tldr; it's not possible to select last-of-class, but it soon will be (and safari already supports it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:last-of-type` selector just finds the last child of a given element type (i.e. the html tag name, `p`, `div`, `li`, etc.). It's not considering any of the other parts of your selector.

The CSS Selectors Level 4 specification adds a new feature for `:nth-child` in [section 14.13.1](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo):

> The :nth-child(An+B [of S]? ) pseudo-class notation represents elements that are among An+Bth elements from the list composed of their inclusive siblings **that match the selector list S, which is a <compound-selector-list> parsed as a forgiving selector list**. If S is omitted, it defaults to *|*.

What this means is that, according to the level 4 spec, you should be able to write CSS like this to select by class name or other criteria:

```css
li:nth-last-child(1 of .test) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="test">hello</li>
  <li class="test">foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

Support for this is relatively recent; Chrome added it in [Jan 2023](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304163), Firefox in [March 2023](https://groups.google.com/a/mozilla.org/g/dev-platform/c/eQeeFKYJ038). [Browser support overview.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-nth-child-of)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see from the screen grab why you need the `last-of-type`?

Wouldn't `table tr td:not(.ds-dt-sticky-cell)` do what you want? Or are there multiple `.ds-dt-sticky-cell` tds in each tr?

Or do you mean you want to target the last cell in each row - except for when it's `.ds-dt-sticky-cell`?

`table tr td:last-child:not(.ds-dt-sticky-cell) { background: red; }`

Comment: Hi Martin, I just wanted to add a slight (scroll-dependent) shadow before the first sticky column. Just to have a nice visual effect.